# Exception Error when container having space in htmlId?

Tags: magento2.2.2, custom-theme

*I encounter this error when override `empty.xml` Layout* for custom theme

I got this error

> 1 exception(s):
>   Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Config\Dom\ValidationException): Element 'container', attribute 'htmlId': [facet 'pattern'] The value 'page-content inset' is not accepted by the pattern '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z\d-_:]*'.
>   Line: 21
>
> Element 'container', attribute `htmlId`: 'page-content inset' is not a valid value of the atomic type `htmlIdentifierType`.
>   Line: 21

[image]

when I tried to set container with Id having space

[image]

I want to know how it's works.

> it's work fine when i change id from `page-content inset` to `page-content-inset`

Comment: yes we should not use space in ID

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The value of the `htmlId` attribute must be matched by the regular expression  `[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z\d-_:]`.

`[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z\d-_:]` means

- Start with a letter (uppercase or lowercase)
- rest of the characters can be:

  - a letter (uppercase or lowercase)
  - a digit (0 to 9)
  - the character `-` (minus)
  - the character `_` (underscore)
  - the character `:` (colon)

That's it. You are not allowed to have spaces (or any other characters except the ones above) inside an id.